# Limit with fractional part involving cosine

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

> Find
>   $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty}\left\{2n^2\cos\left(1 \over n\right)\right\}
> \cos\left(1 \over n\right)
> $$
>   where $\left\{x\right\}= x - \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$ is the fractional part.

Please help me solve it. I know that $\cos\left(n\right) < n$ and that this applies also for $\sin$.

Comment: So the answer should be 1 ?

Comment: I found the answer $\infty$

Comment: @Goendo $0 \leq \left\{\cdots\right\} < 1$.

Comment: Numerically, it 'seems' to be $\color{red}{0}$.

Comment: Yes, @FelixMarin, I came to my answer by trying $n=100$.

Answer (score 3):

This is fiendish.
First, of course, the factor $\cos\frac1n$ changes nothing, since its limit as $n\to\infty$ is $1$. Thus we concentrate on the other factor, involving Fractional Part.

Now, consider an *integer* that’s large, $n$. Then
$$\cos\frac1n=1-\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{24n^4}-\star\quad,
$$ where the “$\star$” represents something really tiny, and ignorable in comparison with the $\frac1{24n^4}$-term. Now, when we multiply the displayed quantity by $2n^2$, what’s its fractional part? It’s just the $\frac1{24n^4}-\star$, which is positive and small, approaching zero as $n\to\infty$. Of course this calculation depends strongly on $n$ being an integer.

Thus the limit exists, and is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=2x^2\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x>0$.

It is easy to see that $f$ is continous in $\mathbb{R}^{+}$.

Since, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(n) = \infty$,
we have, by intermediate value theorem, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\{f(n)\}$ does not exist.

Therefore, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\{f(n)\}.\cos(\frac{1}{n})$ does not exist. As, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\cos(\frac{1}{n}) = 1$

Justification of above argument:

If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\{f(n)\}.\cos(\frac{1}{n})$ exists, let $P(n) = \{f(n)\}.\cos(\frac{1}{n})$.

Then, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{P(n)}{\cos(\frac{1}{n})} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(n)$. As, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\cos(\frac{1}{n}) = 1 \neq 0$

Comment: so you mean limit $x_{\to 0} x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ does not exist

Comment: limit of product won't exist if  it does not exist for one of the multipliers but exists  **AND** is **non-zero** for the other.

Comment: I dont see how the intermediate value theorem play a role here, for $f$ defined in $\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb R^+$ because both domains are not compact and, in the first case, it is neither connected.

Comment: There is no mention of $n$ being a natural number in the problem, if I am not wrong...